Filter by column - strange behavior
SharePoint online classic view with key filter enabled, in the view alphabetical order, upon selection in filter key of one specific managed metadata, does not allow me to filter by a specific column (only for this MMD and only this view).
I have a library containing 414 documents (it matters only for double check, below, in any case small library), it is displayed with classic experience and key filter component.
The library has a column "year" that is a text field ... I don't know why and was not there when the project started.
On the key filter component, in order to filter documents, there is only 1 Managed Metadata to choose (having around 20 choices).
Displaying the whole library (all documents) I am able to filter by the column year.
When I select one specific MMD (a specific one, it is not happening for others MMD) on key filter I cannot filter by the year having message
"Cannot show the value of the filter….".
This selection has only 34 documents that span 9 possible years.
There are other selections (different MMDs selected by key filter) with more than 34 documents (spanning more than 9 years) and there I am able to filter by year.
I checked that all the documents contain a number in the year column: exported library in excel and calculated length of the year cell, all are 4 (+ mean value is 4 and the total is 1656 i.e.4*414, it means all the records have a number even if the column is a text)
So the column can be filtered (it is in the main view of the library with all documents, and it is filtered with others MMD), We are far from the limit of 5000 items, And the limit of the tenant seems to be not related to this case since filter by works with bigger selections.
Moreover this is happening only in one specific view (alphabetical order) the same operations: Selecting the MMD inside key filter and then using the column year to filter works in another view of the same library.
Looking for a hint. Thanks.
